# How to add flavour coating to gelatine or starch capsules?

Tags: flavor

I have gelatine and starch capsules of differing colours and sizes that I use for supplements and the like. In some cases, I would like to coat the capsules with differing flavours! A sort of sensory auto-suggestion before a workout, so to speak.

So how would I add flavour coating to gelatine or starch capsules?

Comment: I think flavor coating might be counterproductive.  In order to taste the coating you have to leave the capsule in contact with your tongue, which would hydrate it, making it stickier and more difficult to swallow and more prone to breakage.  Generally the purpose of capsulizing supplements is to avoid their taste, so breakage/dissolving is to be avoided.

Comment: @Didgeridrew Whether a second or two of saliva induces that level of friction, depends on the type of capsule. In any case, whilst some supplements (like fish oil) are somewhat unpalatable, for other supplements and compounds the use of capsules allows for precise pre-measurement so you don't have to use tiny spoons, pipettes and scales each day.

Comment: @Didgeridrew Still, pills often have a lightly sweet coating, for example. You don't have to leave it on your tongue for extra long to taste it; you'll get the flavor while it's on your tongue before you swallow it normally.

Answer (score 1):

use a spritzer bottle to spray a (VERY LIGHT) mist of flavored water on them. make sure not to get the pills too wet or they will be ruined.

Comment: Completely a theory here -- if you did this, and then rolled it through some powder (eg, the inside of pixie sticks), you might get adhesion of the coating w/out having all of the capsules stick together.  It's also possible that there's a liquid that could serve as the adhesive without affecting the gelatin too much.  (alcohol?)

Comment: that's an awesome idea, and in the case where you don't want to use flavored liquid a flavored sugar coating would work. If you have a flavored liquid and don't want a flavored powder coating corn starch would be a great option.